# Position label behind input tag

Tags: html, css, input, label, positioning

I have some HTML/CSS [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8F6vR/2/) that I need to modify. Originally the CSS was defined for the following HTML structure:

```
  <span>
     <input></input>
  </span>
  <label></label>
```

Where the label is positioned behind the input using z-index values. Now my HTML structure has changed to this:

```
  <span>
     <input></input>
     <label></label>
  </span>
```

And I need the same behavior. I've tried messing with z-index values for the input and label without any success. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the background `url("http://s2.postimage.org/5u8nbrl0/field_a.png") no-repeat` and `position` and `z-index` from the `span` to the `input`

```
form.form-a p span.f input { 
    ...
    background: url("http://s2.postimage.org/5u8nbrl0/field_a.png") no-repeat; 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

It has an invisible background and therefore you can see the label behind it even when you change the z-index.

Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8F6vR/23/)

Comment: The invisible background totally threw me off. You're awesome, thanks!